# Self Hosted WCF via MSMQ Simple Injector Lifestyle

Tags: vb.net, wcf, dependency-injection, msmq, simple-injector

I'm using WCF (self-hosted) using MSMQ bindings and wanted to use the [Per WCF request lifestyle with SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#perwcfoperation).  I setup my code as:

```
Dim httpLifecycle = New SimpleInjector.Integration.Wcf.WcfOperationLifestyle(True)
container.Register(of ISomeType, SomeType)(httpLifecycle)
```

Over MSMQ, this doesn't work, as I get the error:

> The dependency resolver for the web services host failed to
>   initialize: SimpleInjector.ActivationException: The registered
>   delegate for type ILoader threw an exception. The ISomeType is
>   registered as 'WCF Operation' lifestyle, but the instance is requested
>   outside the context of a WCF Operation.

Is there a way the WCF request lifestyle an work with MSMQ?

Comment: I don't have any experience with MSMQ over WCF, but you might want to try the WAS registration [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wcfintegration.html#was-hosting-and-non-http-activation).

Comment: I went through those steps, but it fails when it gets to the registration (the RegisterPerWcfOperation call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a per execution scope and defining that scope within the WCF service operation itself.  By scoping it that way, it ensured the dependencies opened and closed when I wanted them to.

I needed to include [execution context scoping](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Extensions.ExecutionContextScoping/).